# MSBuild remove files on clean

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-task

I have the following target that gets called AfterBuild

```
<Target Name="CopyAppDeployableArtifacts">
    <ItemGroup>
      <MyFiles Include="App_DeployableArtifacts\**\*.*" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(MyFiles)" DestinationFiles="@(MyFiles->'$(OutputPath)\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)')" />
  </Target>
```

I've noticed that doing a clean of my solution leaves folders that get copied by this command in the bin.

What is the best way to do a reverse of this copy and have those folders removed upon cleaning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extend the built in clean functionality of msbuild, See Sayeds Blog:http://www.sedodream.com/PermaLink,guid,670b78b1-4968-46b1-905b-3ae903f3d9cb.aspx